# Is $\{ (3,0,0) , (1,1,0) , (2,2,2) , (1,3,5) \} $ a basis for $\mathbb{R}^3$?

Tags: linear-algebra

I need to check if 
 $S$ = { (3,0,0) , (1,1,0) , (2,2,2) , (1,3,5) }  is a base for $R^3$

So i need to verify if the set $S$ is linear independent and is a linear span of $R^3$

First i'm trying to check if the set $S$ is a linear span $R^3$

$a(3,0,0) + b(1,1,0) + c(2,2,2) + d(1,3,5) = (x,y,z)$ , Then:

$$
\left\{ 
\begin{array}{c}
3a+b+2c+d=x \\ 
b+2c+3d=y \\ 
2c+5d=z
\end{array}
\right. 
$$

Ok, after creating this system of equations what i do next? I find $a,b,c$ and $d$ in terms of $x,y$ and $z$? Doesn't seems like a easy task. Even if a find, then what is my conclusion?

Comment: How can four things be a basis of three dimensions?

Answer (score 1):

A set of $n+1$ vectors in $R^n$ will always be linearly dependent.

For example, using your vectors you can see that $-\frac{2}{3}(3,0,0)+-2(1,1,0)+\frac{5}{2}(2,2,2)=(1,3,5).$

It is not a basis, because it is not linearly independent. It does span $\mathbb{R}^3$.

EDIT:

If you want to check it spans $\mathbb{R}^3$, we can do it with the first three vectors (we deduced the fourth vector above from the first three so it is redundant).

I would do it like this: Given $(x,y,z)$

$\begin{align}
     &   
         a\begin{pmatrix}
           3 \\           
           0 \\
           0
          \end{pmatrix} +
          b\begin{pmatrix}
           1 \\
           1 \\
           0
         \end{pmatrix}+
    c\begin{pmatrix}
           2 \\
           2 \\
           2
         \end{pmatrix}=
\begin{pmatrix}
           x \\
           y \\
           z
         \end{pmatrix}
  \end{align}$

Note $2c=z$ then $c=\frac{1}{2}z$.

Note $b+2c=y$ but we know $c=\frac{1}{2}z$ then $b+z=y\implies b=y-z$.

Note $3a+b+2c=x$ but $b=y-x, c=\frac{1}{2}z$ then $3a+(y-z)+z=3a+y=x\implies a=\frac{1}{3}(x-y)$

Then any $(x,y,z)$ can be written as a linear combination of the first three vectors.

Comment: Please, how do i check if spans R^3

Comment: Also, to check the dependence i will have the same system as above but instead of x,y and z i will have the equations equal to 0, right? If a have more variables than equations i can say that exist infinite solutions, thefore the vectors will be linearly dependent?

Comment: I added a part to check the first three vectors span $\mathbb{R^3}$.

I didn't understand your second comment. The first part already show dependence of the four vectors. The last thing you said seems right.

Answer (score 1):

Any basis for a vector space of dimension n must satisfy 
1) The vectors in the basis span the vector space.
2) The vectors in the basis are linearly independent.
3) There are n vectors in the basis.

And any two imply the third.  So any set of four vectors **cannot** be a basis for a vector space of dimension three.

Comment: Maybe my question is badly written. My problem is to find how does the 4 vectors above generate R^3

Comment: I'm not clear what "generate R^3" means.  It should be clear that the [b]three[/b] vectors (3, 0, 0), (1, 1, 0), and (2, 2, 2) are independent so any vector In R^3 can be written as a linear combination of those three.    It is not **quite** so obvious that, in fact, any three of those four vectors are independent and so will span the space.

Comment: By "generate" i'm mean span R^3. How do i check if the 4 vectors above spans R^3.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that algorithmically: write the vectors coordinates as row vectors of a matrix, and find it rank via row reduction:
\begin{align}
\begin{bmatrix}
3&0&0\\1&1&0\\2&2&2\\1&3&5
\end{bmatrix} \rightsquigarrow
\begin{bmatrix}
1&0&0\\1&1&0\\2&2&2\\1&3&5
\end{bmatrix} \rightsquigarrow
\begin{bmatrix}
1&0&0\\0&1&0\\0&2&2\\0&3&5
\end{bmatrix}  \rightsquigarrow
\begin{bmatrix}
1&0&0\\0&1&0\\0&0&2\\0&0&5
\end{bmatrix} \rightsquigarrow
\begin{bmatrix}
1&0&0\\0&1&0\\0&0&1\\0&0&5
\end{bmatrix} \rightsquigarrow
\begin{bmatrix}
1&0&0\\0&1&0\\0&0&1\\0&0&0
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align}
Thus the rank is $3$, and the first three vectors make up a basis.